# How to dynamically filter to only dates in 2 months time using Excel PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm using Excel and PowerQuery to show different tables of data, each table showing the data for that month. I'm using the built-in date operators 'This Month' and 'Next Month' but there's not one for 2 months time.

I can select an arbitrary month, but that doesn't work because I need the data in the tables to automatically refresh when we move to the next month.

I can see in the advanced editor that the formula for next month is = `Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each Date.IsInNextMonth([#"Forecast Date (DD/MM/YYYY)"]))` but I can't work out how to adapt this to show 2 months time...

Any help/guidance much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `greater than...less than` method and construct your dates based on **Today**'s date:

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", 
        each [dates] >= #date(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()),Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow())+1,1) 
        and [dates] < #date(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()),Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow())+2,1))
```

where `[dates]` is your column containing the dates you want to filter, and `Changed Type` is the previous line in your code.